# Table loses CSS style on ajax reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table, reload

I have a table with the `id="example"`. I also have a button which will reload the table on click.

```
 <button id="refresh-btn">Refresh Table</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   function RefreshTable() {
       $( "#example" ).load( document.URL + ' #example' );
   }

   $("#refresh-btn").on("click", RefreshTable);
</script>
```

After clicking the button and reload, the table refreshes but loses its CSS style.
Before ajax reload:

[image]

After ajax reload:

[image]

[The link to my table.](https://fnwebs.com/test/)

I appreciate any help.

Comment: How is the CSS loaded originally?

Comment: have you tried to debug? ctrl+shift+i ? probably there is more code related to this btn

Comment: On the top of the page.

Comment: Is it some plugin or something? My guess is it is not CSS, but you had JavaScript or something with what you are loading....

Comment: Is it because you are loading the example into example so you end with nested examples which may cause formatting issues?

Comment: I tried to debug and I can see that my table is doubled after reload.

Comment: @Florin Then you should not do the `load` on `#example` but on its parent.

Comment: I'll try it, thank you guys.

Comment: Or wrap the table in a div and load into that div (if the parent has other html in)

Comment: you are probably going to have to re-initialise your datatables plugin (or whatever plugin you use) in the success callback function of your load